# Why it is so difficult to treat leukemia?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, hematology

I want to ask what is the reason that T315I type CML leukemia is currently untreatable. I have read quite a few papers in this subject. Why the current genetic oriented engineering drugs failed to stop the leukemia stem cell's expansion but can only slow the secondary leukemia stem cell's expansion? I found it to be utterly hopeless for a patient to be in such a position, as chemical therapy does not work well and radiation therapy can only target specific area. There are experimental drugs in the developmental stage but from what I know they are mostly unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

The T315l mutation of BCR/ABL gene produce the complete resistance of CML leukemia to all currently available BCR/ABL inhibitors.

There is a idea that is not yet tested for such patients - allogenic hematopoietic transplatation.

More information: 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20657522
http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/maney/hem/pre-prints/1607845412Y.0000000050

Comment: While this helps, it does not answer my question. But thanks.